# Web sharing, 404

Tags: macos, sharing, websites

On my MacBook (10.5.latest), I turned on "Web sharing" in the control panel.  The built-in firewall is turned off.  I have an index.html in my ~/name/Sites/ folder.  It's publicly readable (a+r).  I can view it in Safari (or any other browser) if I open it as a file.

If I go to http://192.168.15.103/~name/index.html (or without index.html, or with any other file from that folder), I get a page which says simply:

> 404 - Not Found

What am I missing?  And how do I go about troubleshooting this -- where are the logs?

Comment: The logs are in `/var/log` or `/var/log/apache2`, access_log and error_log are of interest.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason Apple disabled personal web sharing from your ~/username/Sites folder in Mac OS X 10.5. To turn it back on, edit **`/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`** and look for the following:

```
#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Change **`Deny from all`** to **`Allow from all`**. Then go into your Sharing preferences and disable/re-enable web sharing and it should work.

Comment: Found it, changed it, restarted it, still get the 404.  :-(  I was going to be shocked if this was the case, since the control panel says "Your personal website: http://192.168.15.103/~name/".

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure I've used personal web sharing on 10.5 here before, and /private/var/log/apache2/access_log shows a few successful (200) hits to files under ~/name/ in 2008.

Comment: @Ken Are you using your full username? The "/~username/" in the URL is your "short" username. If that's not it I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: could it be a permissions error?  I think it's a different error code for permissions errors but make your index.html permissions are at least 644

Comment: It's the 'short' name (Unix login name, same as the control panel says to use, same as the access logs said I used in 2008).  My index.html is already 644 (that's rw/r/r, IIRC).

Comment: try 777 just as a test. if works you know it was permissions.  not likely, but worth a try :)

Comment: calavera: OK, tried it.  Even making index.html executable doesn't help it be served as a webpage.  :-)

Comment: lol, i know crap about web serving so it was a shot in the dark :P

Comment: can you get to the computer's apache page by going to just the ip address without a user name?

Comment: calavera: Any path I try (including nothing at all) gives the same 404.  But if I try, say, the same IP address on a different port, then Safari gives a very different can't-connect error, so it looks like the 404 is indeed coming from my web server (in case that was in doubt).

Comment: @Ken did you check the permissions of the containing folder (~/username/Sites)? I've occasionally had problems where the permissions on the file were OK but the containing folder were affecting my ability to access the page

Comment: Are you using FileVault?

Comment: ickket no, I'm not

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure if the origins of the problem were same, I faced the exact scenario as you described, and I made the "Your personal website:http://192.168.0.100/~name/" provided in System Preferences panel work by uninstalling Pow, a Rack server.